# Assign many pandas dataframes into variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 200 pandas dataframes.

I know I can do:

```
df1, df2, df3, ..., df200 = [list of 200 dataframes]
```

Is there a way to elegantly assign distinct variable names to each dataframe?

Comment: Don't do that, store them in a dict. You do not want to have 200 variables floating around outside of a container: `d = dict((f'df{i+1}', l[i]) for i in range(len(l)))` where `l` is your list. Now you acces them by `d['df1']`

Comment: @ALollz Thanks. How would you save the into dictionary? I've never done that.

Comment: @ALollz, thank you very much for your suggestion.